# Using google map GDirections with address

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I need to use the google map directions to show the directions between two addresses.

How can i show the google map using addresses?

Also, I have the source and destination addresses (no latitude and longitude), how can I show the directions between the address using jquery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's very easy:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
var directions = new GDirections(map);

directions.load('from: London, UK to: Glasgow, UK');
```

Screenshot:

[image: Using google map GDirections with address]

---

**UPDATE:**

Using the [v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) is a bit more verbose, but still straightforward:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var request = {
  origin: 'London, UK', 
  destination: 'Glasgow, UK',
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: which google script file i need to include?
Is it available in the latest version of GMAP (Version 3)?

Comment: @Prasad: The example I provided was for the v2 API. Therefore you'd need to include the script `http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=false&key=your_api_key`... Let me also update my answer with a v3 API example :)

Comment: @Prasad: I've updated my answer with a v3 API example as well. In this case, you'd need to include the `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false` script.